# Why do far away hills seem blue?

Tags: optics, visible-light

When walking with my grandmother and father in the country recently on a sunny day, I remarked not only on how the hills further away seemed fainter (a fairly obvious observation) but that also how they seemed to be be a tinge blue. Both present agreed - this was something I had never thought about before.

Why is this? Is this some sort of super-small-scale version of Rayleigh scattering?

Comment: Indeed, it’s Rayleigh scattering. There is a lot of air in between you and the hills, scattering blue sunlight towards you.

Comment: See also the answer to this very similar question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/412254/why-is-blue-the-last-colour-to-disappear-underwater